# Cannot solve not all code paths return a value error

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'll be the first to admit I'm no expert but the plugin API offers me no information for my issue.

I have the following code which is meant to set an image source into an image tag in my xaml called Controller2 when the Down button is pressed on the keyboard:

```
public bool OnDown(bool held)
    {
        string path = $"pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Themes/Test/Images/Controls/Atari 2600/Joystick.png";

        BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();

        bitmap.BeginInit();

        bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(path, UriKind.Absolute);

        bitmap.EndInit();

        Controller2.Source = bitmap;
    }
```

And I'm getting a Not all code paths return a value error for OnDown.

The plugin API is found [here](http://pluginapi.launchbox-app.com/html/61f27087-4b9a-424e-73c0-e482cd2bc0b1.htm) but offers no information about what values are expected. Based on my research, I'm supposed to make an If statement but I don't know what I'm checking for.

Advice on how to solve the error is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a bool.

```
public bool OnDown(bool held)
{
    var path = "pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Themes/FamiGami/Images/Controls/Atari 2600/Joystick.png";

    Controller2.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(path));

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Oh geez, I can't believe it was that simple!

Comment: @Sweepster Also note the simpler way of creating a BitmapImage from an Uri.